# accessing method of custom view in view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a new-be in Objective C. Here I want to ask a simple question.
I have created a view controller in `storyboard`, and customized its view with a subclass of `UIView`.
However, I don't know how to call methods of the view in my view controller. Can anyone help? All I want to do is to call `drawLine:pointStore` in `ChartViewController.m` from `chartView.m`

Here are some of my codes.
ChartViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class chartView;

@interface ChartViewController : UIViewController{  
    chartView *chart_view;  
}
```

ChartViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    NSMutableDictionary *pointStore = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];  

    NSNumber *initX;  
    NSNumber *initY;  
    NSMutableDictionary *variableSet = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for(initX = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-10.0f];initX.floatValue<=10.0f;initX = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(initX.floatValue+0.5f)] )
    {
        [variableSet setValue:initX forKey:@"x"];
        initY = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.brain performOperation:equationOfChart withVariable:variableSet]];
        [pointStore setObject:initX forKey:initY];
    }
    [chart_view drawLine:pointStore];
}
```

chartView.h

```
@interface chartView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *equation;
-(void) getEquation:(NSString *)Equation;
-(void) drawLine:(NSMutableDictionary *)pointsStore;

@end
```

chartView.m

```
-(void)drawLine:(NSMutableDictionary *)pointsStore{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
    for(NSNumber *ax = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-10.0f];ax.floatValue<10.0f;){
        float ay = [[pointsStore objectForKey:ax]doubleValue];
        ax = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(ax.floatValue+0.5f)];
        int by = [[pointsStore objectForKey:ax]doubleValue];
        [self.class line:ax.floatValue y:ay  x2:(ax.floatValue+0.5) y2:by];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's better. Add another variable called pointStore to chartView like your equation. Then set this after the init of self.chart_view. Then call [self.chart_view setNeedsDisplay] to draw. Don't call drawRect directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChartViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class chartView;

@interface ChartViewController : UIViewController

@property (string, nonatomic) chartView *chart_view;

@end
```

chartView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    ...
    // Don't forget to alloc and init
    self.chart_view = [[chartView alloc] init];
    [self.chart_view drawLine:pointStore];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now working. Since I am going to ask the view to draw somethings, would it be better if I pass pointStore to the view, and call the draw method in drawRect? If so, how might I pass it?

Comment: Ha! I've add a comment below your question.

Comment: I have tried the following
ChartViewController.m  
    {
    ...
    self.chart_view = [[chartView alloc] init];
    self.chart_view.pointStore = [pointStore mutableCopy];
    [self.chart_view setNeedsDisplay];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }
chartView.h
    {...
    property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *pointStore;
    ...
    }
chartView.m
    {...
    synthesize pointStore;
    }
However, it still doesn't work. Did I misunderstand what you teach or what?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the instance of `chart_view` is created and assigned. Probably you have nil in that poiner.

How to do this -- depend on the way you have chosen to create the view: in Interface Builder or dynamically, in code.